# Android layout doesn't show everything

Tags: android, xml, layout

When the main TextView (Test123) has 2 lines, the RadioButtons on the bottom don't show completely. There is a ton of screen space left though. I'm guessing it has to do with the RadioGroup height, but that's why I'm here :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/bkg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tOut"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80px"
        android:textSize="30px"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="Test123" 
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_below="@id/tOut"
        android:id="@+id/ranButton"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/randomize"
        android:onClick="ranButton"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@id/ranButton"
        android:id="@+id/between"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="Between 0 and:"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_below="@id/between"
        android:id="@+id/etMax"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:digits="1234567890"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_below="@id/etMax"
        android:id="@+id/copyButton"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:text="Copy Number"
        android:onClick="copyButton"
        />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_below="@id/copyButton"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/intRb"
            android:layout_below="@id/copyButton"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Whole Number"
            android:checked="true"
            />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/decRb"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Decimal"
            />

    </RadioGroup>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can u plz post whole xml file so that i can paste that at my end.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your layout:

1. Try setting the radio group height to wrap_content
2. Never use px to define a view's height... you should always use dp, since this will act best across multiple devices
3. RelativeLayout doesn't have an orientation property. You should remove it.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

> Hi just checkout the xml file below, i hv edited the xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
     >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tOut"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Test123"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ranButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tOut"
        android:onClick="ranButton" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/between"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/ranButton"
        android:text="Between 0 and:"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etMax"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/between"
        android:digits="1234567890"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/copyButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/etMax"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:onClick="copyButton"
        android:text="Copy Number"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/copyButton"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/intRb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/copyButton"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Whole Number" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/decRb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Decimal" />
    </RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

radioGroup's height should be:
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

intRb doesn't need

```
android:layout_below="@id/copyButton"
```

And if you use a Relative Layout, the height should be

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

and remove

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

if you want the radiogroup to be on the bottom you can use
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
and use layout_XXXX="@id/something" where XXXX is below, above, toRightOf etc...

Otherwise, you are better off using a LinearLayout